# Highly Responsive Multi Threaded WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I Am Working on WPF Application to communicate with 16 Devices through Serial Port. Communication Process includes read and write Commands. Configuration of device takes around 2 minutes. My UI should be responsive during configuration process, that it should show reading after read commands execution and show command status after write commands execution. I used backgroundworker for handling one device. Everything works fine. Now i need to run all 16 devices simultaneously. How do i do it? Since Only one UI thread is available, UI hangs for 2-3 devices. Please suggest best possible way for this.

Comment: "Since Only UI thread is available" - what do you mean by that?  Why not use `BackgroundWorkers` for all 16 devices?

Comment: Sorry.I mean to say Only one UI Thread. All devices have same operations to do. So i created user control and load 16 user control in One Window and perform complete device communication in background worker. But during communication i need to update UI also. Which is getting hanged.

Comment: How are you communicating?

Comment: Through Serial Port. I fu can elaborate your question i can answer with further details.

Comment: How are you communicating to the UI?

Comment: In Every User control i use backgroundworker to communicate with device and to update UI after command execution i use dispatcher.

Comment: Why can't your UI thread handle the updates from the background worker?  Sounds like you're either doing **really** complicated UI updates, or you're trying to push a lot of updates per second.  Can you show us the code?

Comment: Try using ReportsProgress rather than dispatcher to commnicate with UI.  You can pass an object.

Comment: How about using Properties with INotifyPropertyChanged Interface instead of Dispatcher?

Answer (score 1):

you have to have background Worker for each device,
you can report the progress for each device by:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;

   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
       ....
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
       ....
     }

  private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

you can also interact with the UI thread from any thread by using:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
( DispatcherPriority.Normal,new Action(() => { ... }));
```